# Rewire wall switch to an on/off switch, for a ceiling fan that has nightlight, fan & lights?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

How do I rewire a wall outlet to an on/off switch? It's for a ceiling fan that has a dim nightlight above the fan, and lights below the fan?
It also has a Hampton Bay remote.

[image: ceiling fan]
[image: remote]
[image: old switch front]
[image: old switch back]
[image: new switch front]
[image: new switch back]

Any thoughts from the pics.   Again,  trying to go from a multi light fan switch to a single on off switch. My Hampton Bay fan with a dimmer night light and a regular light is controlled by a remote. 
Fan remote has three speeds. One button for night light & one for regular lights.
Multi  Wall switch has a black striped white wire on the back side at the top and the bottom is a black wire on the back side.  The light side has a blue wire on the back at the top  and in the middle at the bottom is the green stripe white wire, ground.

The blue light wire is connected to a red wire on the wall. The fans black stripe white wire is connected to a dark Gray wire on the wall. The  bottom black wire on the fan side is connected to a dark gray wall wire. The Green striped white wire is connected to the copper ground wire on the wall.

If you could help on  basically what wires in the wall to connect to the on off switch to make the nightlight, regular light, and fan speeds operate  when turning the on off switch on and using the remote.

Comment: Do you want the fan remote and the wall switch to effectively have three-way i.e. shared control of the fan (at its current speed) and the light? Or do you want the wall switch to override the fan remote?

Answer (score 1):

Reference [the UC9031 installation instructions (PDF)](http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/pdfImages/5b/5ba7b9fe-8d2e-48b6-90af-a85626b3691b.pdf).  Your picture shows:

[image: visible wires labeled]

And the backside of that model:
[image: Switch backside schematic]

Is there another wirenut not shown?  Otherwise, there is no separate connection for the nightlight.

In order to be able to switch off everything at the wall you will need:

1. Short length of #12 or #14 wire for pigtail(s).
2. Larger wirenut sufficient for joining 4 wires. Those yellow nuts are not big enough.

The new switch should be wired like:

[image: New switch wiring]

1. Make sure power is off and consult an electrician if you're unsure about anything.
2. Label all the wires from the wall before disconnecting the old switch.
3. Leave the neutral alone.
4. Wire the fan, light, a 6 to 8 inch pigtail, and the nightlight wire (if any) together.
5. Connect the other end of the pigtail to the switch as shown.